# Branching points, Point at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying multivalued functions in complex analysis, more precisely I was reading about the $n-th$ root $z = \omega^{1/n}$. In my professor's lecture notes it is said that, for $n = 2$, namely the square root, the point $w=0$ is a branching point of order $2$, because if *we go around* the point twice, or in other words we consider a curve that loops twice around it, then $\sqrt{w}$ starts taking its initial values again. After reading a bit about Riemann surfaces (mine's not a complex analysis course, just a smaller version of a standard course for physicists, so many things like Riemann surfaces can't be covered) I then comprehended what a branching point of order $2$ stands for intuitively. Now, the lecture notes then affirm that the point at infinity is a branching point of order $2$ as well, and we can see it by substituting $z \to 1/\zeta$ when $\zeta \to 0$, thus obtaining
$$ \sqrt{\omega} \to \sqrt{1/\zeta}$$
The problem is: what does this last function tell me? I cannot understand why it has a branching point at infinity. The only thing I can imagine is taking a curve that goes around the point at infinity on the Riemann sphere (north pole). But mathematically, how can one see this fact? Furthermore, is it a coincidence that the order of the two branching points is the same?
I don't know if I've been totally clear, my ideas are a bit confused, to be honest. It's my first time dealing with multivalued functions, so I'm trying to understand concepts at more of an intuitive level first, if that makes sense.
I'll gladly accept any explanation :)

Comment: Well, what exactly would a curve around infinity look like? In particular, a curve around zero is a curve around infinity in the opposite direction... so the behaviors you saw around zero would still happen around infinity. This actually all sort of ties down to how the branching behavior is exhibited for the complex $\operatorname{log}$ function! If you would like for me to expand, I would love to, I've worked a bit on this myself!

Comment: yes please. And thank you. I can see now that their similar nature is bound to the fact that a curve around zero is also a curve around infinity. But what does the $1/\sqrt{\zeta}, \zeta \to 0$ substitution tell us then?

Comment: The substitution here is to understand that one may extend $\sqrt{w}$ continuously at $\infty$; yet, around the boundary any (small) neighborhood, it behaves like the branch point of order 2, as it is a curve around zero as well (it simply takes the values in 'reverse').

Comment: I realized that to write a more deeper exposition, I would need to set up quite a bit of terminology. I suggest you read Gareth A Jones book _Complex Functions: An Algebraic and Geometric Viewpoint_, **Chapter 3** - he has a section on this particular function and treats it quite visually and well!

Comment: Thank you @PCeltide, I'll check it out